# How do you make sure when you copy an object's members without changing its readonly modifier

Tags: typescript

I came across this typescript challenge [MyReadonly2](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PQKgUABBAcELQQEoFMCGATA9gOwDYE8IAmSeOci0gI0IEFsAXACx0IDEBXCACgAFVGAMw4BKCAGIAtsnQBLDpIkAnNFjyFxmKgCtkAYwZwA1snwBnMKXHWIARQ7IzDWTktQAkpIAOuZNMYQqBAA5sjYyEqyehAABgCy%20CgYOAREADwAKgA0EADSAHwxEADuTFFMEAyoJmaVxZiV%20F7IgUrBCmEMsRlFAuixuTEAdG4DRWbNerKChMwtZshdmIIQXkqYzUrOjhDL3UXMqF1mLBy4-QtdDA1JagRDEADqTGFjELK12Jhda5gAbrJ0DIcrJjqdzhBJNUWqhcLhVutNttaipkuoINoOE4ILhZCZKi8IF8lFD4TFbil8JlCiNSGxMEoIMgAB6oby%20UYxLkMCxQWSMCKCVB6FoZTBYCAAb1IUGcDF8AC4IE5IthgjKIECzHpIl5nDglSr%20eqoFA9Jh2YsZEqqJhML4BKQAL6jc3YbHXLBKhIU9TpMVYHIAcjlviDEAAPhAg1qdbI9S5sEH8hAALxSjWh5BKgBEAAlTDmshrY7r9dhc4I7VRUEoixrzZaGNaIELcAti1AXaRPZghlm0xB88g4ZgcxBgMAIABRJTrJRKvQCL5dVFmMyyYLYQIQVF3Qi-JH4Hvivul%20Plwc5mtKeljidT2fzxfL767tDrzfboJ7ykIjYRAwx6yqeQyNj4Vr9OmDBKA4D4QAA8rkpBcjEowpgAarIyDFLs24AOKgnmHBUEqTAMAwXhmAqk48noTBDNoZhDAywTANAYAgMAligBAAD6AmCUJgkQAAmpgHCMgAwuKLQFio-HCUpfEQFxlhAc0EA%20qolL%20jkuRMsyzbYOgtQmPgewZIO5mWSm6aIZIoKZPpKYAGRSu%20aIEBAADaAAK7zbrkAC6SoZP5wUQN2vHKUpEAZI4XRSagCy1LFwmqdxsjeAyVxNC0koQLQuImDk07MpMXROq26yKEGvAacgcD0bCvhqo4wAcM47ZBup%20UQEuqWDj5pDlZVaTFXiyBpNpXn4P6p4AIz5DkvoEJkS35FtnYzhV%20gMBNJXTbN%204LVgi3Blm4ZRjGjhxgmODJmVe0GDI22jS9B2TSYM2JDpfobVgRCXaCYaRtG54PUmK27ZVb0rR943fcdf1zWdmDAxDd1lom4Yw2N%203w8WwU8VODVmHALKVZTc4MmAjVMrTjLpidumA5gF3Rld4NBvyfywoCyaWPyzZKEKIrxUtGayqD2bKjBxqkJD5YAPyGgraqkOBvjNugNp2g62BgN2IuCsKoqnkQ0uefulSy%20rqompq2MXomavy47WsWhBuv6-aaBGybApi%20bsOE-00pQL%206JZg7itR-93nK27cea2a3s6y2tr%20460UgIp6UCRAnBbC8jIAMrNlRBeF5lYCgKQKbl0wtYtBZknKvaXWJtREDkZR1G0dqDFMSxbTscAAhmMUESNxAWE4Z3uDdzgvf91RNHAHRI-MaxE9mF35a8hAKZxAyLRSS3cJhKEa8URvQ-0Yxu9tJx3FAA). Here is my original solution:

```
// doesn't work as `Exclude` could potentially change the existing `readonly` modifier in the object 
type MyReadonly2<T, K extends keyof T = keyof T> =  { [P in Exclude<keyof T, K>]: T[P] } & { readonly [P in K]: T[P] }
```

Here is one of the correct answers:

```
type MyReadonly2<T, K extends keyof T = keyof T> =  Omit<T, K> & { readonly [P in K]: T[P] }
```

Basically both approaches have the same idea, but how can I make sure I'm not changing the object's readonly modifier when I copy its members? The only difference from `Omit` is just the type constraint on K:

```
type Omit<T, K extends string | number | symbol> = { [P in Exclude<keyof T, K>]: T[P]; }
```

Why does it make a difference?

Comment: Waitwut. I copy `Omit` as `Omit1` and it suddenly *starts losing readonlys*

Comment: Yeah, TS has the concept of a *homomorphic* mapped type (which preserves optional/readonly modifiers) and it kicks in only in certain circumstances; either with `{[P in keyof ⋯]: ⋯}` or `{[P in K]: ⋯}` where `K extends keyof ⋯`.  If you try to "inline" a homomorphic mapped type you might well break that part of it.  See the linked q/a for more info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`keyof` clause in Typescript results in intermediate type with readonly/optional metadata

```
type X = keyof {a?: 1} // 'a' & {[optional]: true, [readonly]: false}
```

However, this metadata is lost on any operation with the type

```
type X = keyof {a?: 1} & string // just 'a'
type X = Extract<keyof {a?: 1}, string> // just 'a'
type X = [keyof {a?: 1}] // just ['a']
```

so when you `{ [P in Exclude<keyof T, K>]: T[P] }` you lose that metadata when you `Exclude<keyof T, ...>`
Use `{ [P in keyof T as P extends K ? never : P>]: T[P] }` instead

Also,

```
type Omit2<T, K extends string | number | symbol> = { [P in Exclude<keyof T, K>]: T[P]; }
```

is not a correct implementation (even if that's the one TS builtin **shows**) as it loses `readonly`s.

https://tsplay.dev/N7z2qw